# Cycles between two vertices in a directed graph

Tags: data-structures, graph, graph-theory

I know that in an undirected graph you have to have at least three vertices to form a cycle. My question is, in a *directed* graph, is it considered a cycle if two vertices have two edges pointing to each other?

Here is an example:

[image]

Is this a cyclic graph?

Related questions:

- [In an undirected graph, the simplest cycle must have 3 nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242390/in-an-undirected-graph-the-simplest-cycle-must-have-3-nodes)
- [Existence of cycle between any two vertices of graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364136/existence-of-cycle-between-any-two-vertices-of-graph)
- [Cycles in an Undirected Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526331/cycles-in-an-undirected-graph)

Comment: I would say that is a cycle, but I’m not aware of any graph police that gets to decide what’s a cycle and what’s not. It would be silly, though, to call it a cycle in an undirected graph, since then any graph with at least one edge is cyclic and the term loses all meaning.

Answer (score 5):

A graph has a cycle if there is a non-empty path that originates at some vertex and ends at the same vertex. In your graph above, you have a cycle on path `A -> C -> A`.  Similarly, let's imagine a directed graph with 2 vertices `A` and `B` and 2 edges `AB` and `BA` (where the first letter is the source vertex).  This means that there is a cycle `A -> B -> A`, thus you can have a cycle in a directed graph of 2 vertices.

Comment: You use the term "graph" and not "directed graph". Are you extending this explanation to undirected graphs?

Comment: Correct. This extends to directed graphs. I'll update my answer to be clearer. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation here. +1. I'm trying to write a formal explanation for other people like me who are new to graph theory. Do you know of any official references that say what you are saying? I was having trouble finding any.

Comment: I don't have my old college textbook lying around, but the Wikipedia definition of a cycle leads to that logic.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it (A-C-A) is a cycle. But I am from a different perspective: you may know that for a directed **acyclic** graph (dag), there is a topological sorting on it; otherwise, there isn't.

Topological sorting is indeed the linear extension of a partial order <=. Thus, dag is the graphical representation of a partial order <=. Be aware that according to the anti-symmetry property of a partial order <= (i.e., if a<=b and b<=a, then a=b), there is no possibility that two edges (a,b) and (b,a) simultaneously exist between two distinct vertices a and b.

In summary, no cycle => exists topological sorting, since no topological sorting on your digraph, thus there must be a cycle (A-C-A).

Answer (score 0):

No,it is not considered a cycle if two vertices have two edges pointing to each other in directed graph. They are called Parallel Edges.

Comment: Parallel edges (or multiple edges) on directed graphs have the same source and destination vertices. You can construct a graph such that there is an edge and back edge creating a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

According to this definition <sup>1</sup>:

> A circuit is a closed trail with at least one edge

A-C is considered a circuit. 
A-C also complies with this definition<sup>2</sup>:

> A cycle is a circuit in which no vertex except the first (which is
> also the last) appears more than once.

so it is also a cycle.

---

<sup>1</sup> source:  https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Circuit 
<sup>2</sup> source:  https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Cycle_(Graph_Theory)

Comment: By this definition wouldn't two connected vertices in an undirected graph also be a cycle?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  It asks about a graph of two vertices.

Comment: @NickClark, In my example the A-C connection is two vertices. I probably should have used the letters A-B to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

No, because you wouldn't reuse the edge. You only store outgoing or incoming for the adjacency list representation at least. Therefore, if there is no other edge that can get you back to the other vertex, so there would be no cycle between two vertices in an undirected graph. However, if you did have parallel edges between 2 vertices in an undirected graph I believe that would be a cycle.